# Steel material nodes in blender

Tags: mesh

I would like to apply a steel material to plate &fork which i have modelled. Doea anyone know nodes for thos kind of material?

Comment: Chocofur always has cool ideas: http://www.chocofur.com/4-metal-shaders.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?322941-Realistic-Silver-Material-in-Cycles) Blender Artists thread has some great ideas. One of the best (created by IkariShinji) produces **Img 1**'s result using **Img 2**'s node setup. A decent scratches map can be found by Googling "scratches map."

*Img 1:*

[image]

*Img 2:*

[image]

Comment: Are these someone else's images that you are re-posting? At least give them some attribution!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks allot, will be really useful.